# Changing numeric base for binary trees

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I'm trying to figure an algorithm for changing the base of the numeric binary trees.
For example, lets say I have a set of trees in base of 8 and the main root is 4, and I need to scan the tree and change it to base of 5 (I can assume that the tree can be changed)
[image]

I can't seem to come up with the formula, I know I must do it using recursion, but as soon as I change 1 root, im loosing all connections for it's sons.
How can I handle this?

Comment: Add the children to the new root before you update the old root.

Comment: I'm not able to understand. Are you trying to change the values in the nodes from one base to another?

Comment: yes, im trying to change the values from base of 8 to base of 5 (or something else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pseudo code for doing it:-

```
    void preorder(node* p) {

      if(p==null)
          return

      p->data = change_base(p->data,oldbase,newbase);
      preorder(p->left);  
      preorder(p->right);

    }


    int change_base(int k,int old,int new) {

       base10 = 0;
       while(k>0) {

          base10 = base10*old + k%10;
          k = k/10;
       }

       newbase = 0;

       while(base10>0) {

          r = base10%new;
          newbase = newbase*10 + r; 
          base10 = base10/10; 

      }

     return(newbase);

  }
```